# How to remove index from ArrayList and print total integer of the removed index?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, tostring

I want to make a program for a warehouse. `emptyStock()` method should remove the food that has been sold from the list. `print()` method should print all list of food and total food (kg) that has been sold.

```
public class Lists {
private String name;
private String category;
private int amount;

public Lists(String name, String category, int amount) {
   this.name = name;
   this.category = category;
   this.amount = amount;
}

public String toString() {
    return name + " is " + category + " and we have " + amount + " in warehouse";
}
}

public class Food {
ArrayList<Lists> Food = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(String name, String category, int amount) {
    Food.add(new Lists(name, category, amount));
}

public void emptyStock(int index) {
    Food.remove(index);
}

public void print() {
    for (Lists lists : Food) {
        System.out.println(lists);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Food food = new Food();
    food.add("Potato", "Vegetable", 35);
    food.add("Carrot", "Vegetable", 15);
    food.add("Apple", "Fruit", 30);
    food.add("Kiwi", "Fruit", 5);
    food.emptyStock(1);
    food.emptyStock(2);
    food.print();
    System.out.print("");
}
}
```

The output needs to print something like this:

```
Potato is Vegetable and we have 35 kg in warehouse
Apple is Fruit and we have 30 kg in warehouse
20 kg of food has been sold! // my code cannot print this part
```

I am still not sure how to make `print()` method prints the total amount (kg) of food that has been removed from the list.

Comment: Can you share the Food class code ? Because if you code nothing and waits us to do it, SO is not the good place, do some stuff, face a problem, then ask for some help

Comment: There are lots of details you are missing from your question. What does "remove the index" mean? What does `emptyStock` do? What is your actual question?

Comment: I have edited my post. Thank you.

Comment: Put the food that is removed from the list into a new list of sold items?

Comment: Or only add the weight to an int variable before it is removed from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class member (in class `Food`) that stores the total amount removed. In method `emptyStock()` you update the value of this member. In the below code, I added the member `removed`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Food {
    int removed;
    ArrayList<Lists> foods = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String name, String category, int amount) {
        foods.add(new Lists(name, category, amount));
    }

    public void emptyStock(int index) {
        removed += foods.get(index).getAmount();
        foods.remove(index);
    }

    public void print() {
        for (Lists lists : foods) {
            System.out.println(lists);
        }
        System.out.printf("%d kg of food has been sold!%n", removed);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food food = new Food();
        food.add("Potato", "Vegetable", 35);
        food.add("Carrot", "Vegetable", 15);
        food.add("Apple", "Fruit", 30);
        food.add("Kiwi", "Fruit", 5);
        food.emptyStock(1);
        food.emptyStock(2);
        food.print();
        System.out.print("");
    }
}

class Lists {
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private int amount;

    public Lists(String name, String category, int amount) {
       this.name = name;
       this.category = category;
       this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " is " + category + " and we have " + amount + " in warehouse";
    }
}
```

Output when running above code is:

```
Potato is Vegetable and we have 35 in warehouse
Apple is Fruit and we have 30 in warehouse
20 kg of food has been sold!
```